# how do i remove an item from a list and add it to the end of the same list

Tags: python, list, shuffle

i have a list of 52 tuples (a deck of playing cards) that i'm trying to shuffle without using random.shuffle (not allowed to use it for this project).  what i'm trying to do is create 2 random indices, remove those items from the list and put 1 at the front and 1 at the end of the list.

i can create the random #'s, but not sure how to move them.  seems like .pop is my best method, but not sure if that's right or not.

```
def shuffle():
    ite = 0
    while ite <= 1000:
        rand1 = randint(0, len(card_deck) -1)
        rand2 = randint(0, len(card_deck) -1)
        card_deck.pop[rand1]
        card_deck.append(rand1)
        ite += 1
shuffle()
```

Comment: This is a side issue but it would more Pythonic to use `for ite in range(1001):` instead of the `while` loop.

Comment: Does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pop's time complexity is not ideal in this situation. It would make more sense to store the value at rand1 as a temporary variable and replace it with the value at rand2, then replace the value at rand2 with the temporary variable. And even more efficient as mentioned in the below comment, you can swap two values without a temporary variable.

If you have a list of 1000 items for example, and you want to pop out the 500th item, it will run in N(500) time. Whereas you can access an item in a list in constant time.

If you're doing this as homework, try not to look at my answer below without implementing first by yourself.

```
def shuffle():
    ite = 0
    while ite <= 1000:
        rand1 = randint(0, len(card_deck) - 1)
        rand2 = randint(0, len(card_deck) - 1)
        card_deck[rand1], card_deck[rand2] = card_deck[rand2], card_deck[rand1]
        ite += 1
```

Comment: The temp storage variable is not needed.  Python has tuple assignment `x, y = y, x`

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I've updated my answer to reflect your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sean Payne points out; `pop()` is not the way to go.  `pop()`is terribly slow when all you want to do is swap around values.  Python allows (encourages) tuple assignment, so one can swap values without using a temporary storage location `x, y = y, x`, or in this case `deck[i], deck[j] = deck[j], deck[i]`.

A `for` loop is more pythonic than a `while` loop.

I'm guessing that your instructor is trying to get you to write a proper Knuth shuffle ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)), also called Fisher-Yates, or Fisher-Yates-Knuth.  Durstenfeld was another significant contributor to the algorithm.

```
import random

def shuffle(deck):
    for i in range(len(deck)-1, 0, -1):
        j = random.randint(0,i)
        deck[i], deck[j] = deck[j], deck[i]
    return deck

mydeck = list(range(52))
print(mydeck)
print(shuffle(mydeck))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7JDgIhDIbvPAVHSNC4xIuJT2LmYAScjmzpMId5emS1adLl/7qEPc7eXVMCGzxGii8nvSVEKk3XedPaKCbV@8vvhGbTHilQcIX7KGaUa@rhLKp3rNhCH33bsQRwkZ0E8L9e5p4wiZYsU8Z7JoZWWVRxQ1dbhNi9xIwaWCNrT9wunJOA5UCTRzX@712e0g8)

The big difference to note is that once you choose which item goes to the end of the list that you are working with, leave it there.  If you continue to generate numbers that allow your already shuffled items to be re-shuffled it actually reduces the randomness of the shuffle.  [Mike Bostock](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/) and [Jeff Atwood](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-danger-of-naivete/) both have very good explanations of this problem.

If you *really* want to shuffle to both the front and the back, you could do something like

```
import random

def shuffle2(deck):
    back_of_deck = len(deck) - 1
    for i in range(len(deck)//2):
        front = random.randint(i,back_of_deck)
        back = random.randint(i,back_of_deck)
        deck[i], deck[front] = deck[front], deck[i]
        deck[back_of_deck], deck[back] = deck[back], deck[back_of_deck]
        back_of_deck -= 1
    return deck

mydeck = list(range(52))
print(mydeck)
print(shuffle2(mydeck))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVFBDoMgELzzij1CgjW16aVJX9IYYxUqUcEgHnw9FRCiSQ/lAjM7swvDtJpOyZu1YpyUNqBr2aoRoZZxmLuF84EVuGVNTx4ItvWum75SvHIUPGFgMlQhg6sXcKVBgJCu04fhJMjzYm/hVVpJs/nDuIvbhDRY0GN/kuSO/V/t0EuUNBz8qHJzHxCNmrPn2C5qHJfcHtAf4tNNUz7Zcw9FM7No6X0IjWsMT8wGh5juBSFo0u5VoRxR@oOdJtZ@AQ)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
import random

def build_deck():
    '''
    build a fresh sorted deck of cards
    '''
    nums = range(1,14)
    types = ['Heart','Spade','Club','Diamond']
    deck = [(x,y) for x in types for y in nums]
    return deck


def get_random_indices(from_=1,to=50):
    '''
    get 2 random indices to choose from which are not similar
    '''
    index1 = random.randint(from_,to)
    index2 = random.randint(from_,to)
    if index1 == index2:
        index1,index2 = get_random_indices(from_,to)
    return index1,index2


def shuffle_deck(deck,n_times=52):
    '''
    shuffle deck n times
    '''
    if n_times>0:
        index1,index2 = get_random_indices()
        card1 = deck.pop(index1)
        card2 = deck.pop(index2)
        deck.append(card1)
        deck.insert(0,card2)
        n_times-=1
        shuffle_deck(deck,n_times=n_times)
    return deck

deck = build_deck()
new_deck = shuffle_deck(deck,52)
new_deck
```

You can add extra randomness by choosing the whether card1 should be inserted or appended by using `random.choice()`